# Using the created nested attribute object after parent is saved in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to access a created object that is created using nested attributes when the parent item is saved, and I'm not sure how to do that. My current setup is such:

foo-model.rb

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bars
end
```

bar-model.rb

```
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
end
```

foos-controller.rb

```
class FoosController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @foo = Foo.create(foo_params)

    if @foo.save
      # What I want to do is essentially this
      bar.do_something

      # Redirect
      redirect_to path
    end
  end

  private

  def foo_params
    params.require(:foo).permit(:attribute, bar_attributes: [:id, :attribute1])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Foo.create will trigger the 'save' event.  Instead, do this

```
class FoosController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @foo = Foo.new(foo_params)

    if @foo.save
      redirect_to path
    end
  end

end
```

In the model, add

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bars

  after_save :bars_do_something

  def bars_do_something
    bars.each{|b| b.do_something}
  end
end
```

Instead of updating the foo.bars in an each (not a good idea, according to [law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)), you could update bar after it's created

```
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo

  after_create :do_something

  def do_something
    do_something
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use `::new`, not `::create` on `Foo`.

```
def create
  @foo = Foo.new(foo_params)

  if @foo.save
```

After the `#save` call, you are then free to do any action on the associated `Bars`:

```
if @foo.save
  @foo.bars.each do |bar|
    bar.do_something
  end
```